# Covariant Casting Solution Needed

Tags: c#, casting, covariance

I have the following code using a custom `Maybe.cs` solution

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using FluentAssertions;
namespace FunctionalExtensions.Specs
{
    [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestClass]
    public class TestMaybe
    {
        class Base { }
        class A : Base { }
        class B : Base { }

        [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestMethod]
        public void TestCovariance()
        {
            A a = new A();
            Maybe<A> ma = a.ToMaybe();
            Maybe<A> maa;
            Base b = a;

            Maybe<Base> mb = ma;
            Maybe<Base> mbb = b.ToMaybe();


            // This works
            (mb is Some<A>).Should().BeTrue ();
            maa = (Some<A>)(mb as object);



            // This doesn't
            (mbb is Some<A>).Should().BeTrue ();
            maa = (Some<A>)(mbb as object);
        }
    }
}
```

The `Maybe.cs` implementation is at [Maybe Implementation in C# — Gist](https://gist.github.com/4257876) and is a bit long to paste into the question. Basically, I have an instance of

```
object
```

I need to detect at run-time if I can convert it to a

```
Some<A>
```

However note that this requires an implicit cast to work I think. My guess is that I am stuck with the fact that I can't define an implicit conversion off an interface ( part of the c# standard ) and Some is an interface. Some has to be an interface to make it
covariant ( another part of the C# standard )

Any guess on how to overcome this or am I stuck completely?

Comment: The question is a little confusing as it stands. You say you "I need to detect at runtime if I can convert it to a `Some<A>`". That would be `x as Some<A>`. So presumably you mean something else?

Comment: It is the same thing as I have done yes. (mb as object) as Some<A> I think is equivalent but it returns null rather than throw an exception

Comment: The conversion is not trivial because we are dealing with covariant types. It may not be possible in a general way.

Comment: To clarify again: the `as` cast returns `null` to let you know that it is not possible. If you want to know if it is not possible, check to see if the `as` has returned `null`. What do you need to do apart from this? It's not clear from your question as it is currently written.

Comment: I know it is not possible as it stands. I am asking how to make it possible. I cannot write an implicit cast because Some is an interface.

Comment: The correct cast would be if I could provide an implicit cast would be mbb.Bind(v=>((A)v).ToMaybe()) or mbb.Select(v=>(A)v) if I were to use the Enumerable interface to the Maybe class

Comment: I figured a solution for what I was doing. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to Reify the Maybe class.

```
    public static Maybe<T> Reify<T>(this Maybe<T> This)
    {
        if (!This.IsSome())
        {
            return This;
        }
        dynamic v = This.Value();
        var r = ToMaybe(v);
        return r;
    }
```

Once my Maybe are all reified then I can peform normal casting.

```
A a = new A();
Base b = a;
Maybe<Base> m = b.ToMaybe();

Maybe<Base> mr = m.Reify();

Maybe<A> ma;

// Will pass
ma = (Maybe<A>) mr;

// Will fail
ma = (Maybe<A>) m;
```

Dynamic keyword is the magic to unwrap the runtime type.

Comment: Actually the above code doesn't quite work. It seems that the usage of dynamic with a generic function gives random results. Sometimes it reifies the type and sometimes it returns Maybe<object>. I've changed my code to use reflection to do the reification on the dynamic type rather than use generics